# Azure: Best Practice to use a framework/SDK (with .dll) in a work role

Tags: dll, architecture, azure, snapshot, drive

I want to use [GDal/OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) in a work role on Azure.

To use OGR class and methods I have to configure EnvironmentVariable in my WorkerRole and be able to access to my ["OGR directory"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i664H.jpg).

How to deploy this directory (and all of this contents) in each instance of the worker role (maybe lot instances).

I see 4 tracks :

1. Copy my directory in my work role project (VS2010)

- pro: zero difficulties to install but painful
- cons: not simply when I have a directory with a big hierarchy  / painful to switch to another version of OGR

2. Create a .vhg (virtual disk) and mount snapshot of it on each instance

- pro: easy to switch to a new version of OGR
- cons: if the snapshot is store further than local storage/cost of the snapshot (?)

3. Create a .vhg, mount it, copy the directory, unmount it and work

- pro: easy to switch to a new version of OGR
- cons: access concurrency in the begin of the Run method?

4. Create a .zip, store it in a blob, download it and un-zip in each instance.

- pro: easy to switch to a new version of OGR / others?
- cons: I don't know, says me

Currently, I use the first, but when I'll create others projects or worker role it looks painful.

I don't well know to use the zip method.

If you have comments, others ways, preferences I'm listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benjamin, I have created several similar projects for partners and discussed what could be the best approach for such kind of projects where whole code + runtime + static data, it all bundled together and deployed to a Worker Role and my personal preference is #4 in your list. Take a look at my [Tomcat/Azure in Worker Role](http://tomcatazure.codeplex.com/) which also follow the same deployment model.

You can use the above deployment model for your OGR application deployment to Windows Azure Worker Role.

Also I am not sure, you would want to use newly released [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/) as you can choose Windows Azure VM to just get the VM and deploy directly without any dependency on Windows Azure SDK/Worker Role (just something to think if that applies to your project)

Comment: After have talked with colleagues, I think keep the zip method. Thank you for shared your point of view.